# $f(n) = n + 1$ (if $n$ is odd), $\frac{n}{2}$ (if $n$ is even) where $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have made the above-mentioned observation by myself. My claim is that the last value of all outputs that we get after putting any positive integer in the function is $1$. After that the output would repeat itself in the cycle of $2, 1$.

---

$f(1)$, $f(2)$ are true

Let $n > 2$, then

$1.$ Firstly notice that the output of the function is always a positive integer

$2.$ So if we prove that the function is decreasing, then the last output value will obviously be the least positive integers that is one

$3.$ In the function if the input is odd, then the function increases the input by one, if the number is even the function divides the number by $2$

So if we prove that the decrease in the number $n$, that is $\frac{n}{2}$, is always greater than the increase in the number $n$, that is $1$, then clearly we will have proven that the output of the function decreases.

We have

$n > 2 \implies \frac{n}{2} > 1$

Hence, we are done

(I had a solution which was much more detailed since I am on a mobile phone I wasn't able to elaborate more properly)

Any other idea if anyone has do provide it
I will try that also

Comment: Your general logic makes sense to me, and appears correct.  You might want to provide the more formal proof that you mentioned when you have a moment.  It would also be helpful to put the statement in the description, and not just the title.

Comment: "(I had a solution which was much more detailed since I am on a mobile phone I wasn't able to elaborate more properly)"  Shades of Fermat.... :)  So if you die in a car crash will we spend 300 years trying to replicate your proof?

Comment: I'd formalize that $f_k(x)$ means interating $k$ times and prove for $n > 2$ than $f_2(n) = \begin{cases} \frac {n+1}2 = \frac n2+\frac 12=n-\frac n2+12<n-1+\frac 12=n-\frac 12<n\\ \frac n2+1=n-\frac n2+1<n-1+1=n\end{cases}$.

Comment: "My claim is that the last value of all outputs that we get after putting any positive integer in the function is 1"  Well, not quite.  You get an infinite repeat sequence of $2\to 1\to 2 \to 1 \to 2\to 1\to......$

Comment: @fleablood yes I meant that only after the first time we get 1 then it will repeat itself in a cycle of 2,1

Comment: @S.A.Lloyd ok I will edit the whole thing but any hint or particular idea which portion of my answer needs more explanation?

Comment: Your argument is good and valid but you can improve on your descriptions and a little more.  "the last value of all outputs that we get after putting any positive integer in the function" isn't very clear. Perhaps it'd be clear to say something like "what ever integer we start with after successive iterations we will always inevitibly arrive at on output of $2$ and any further iterationing of the would yield an endless cycles of 2 to 1 to 2 to 1, etc"  For 2) you may or may not want to justify it with a Well Ordering principal.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(f(n))=\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}2&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\\frac n2+1&\text{if }n\equiv2\bmod4\\\frac n4&\text{if }4\mid n\end{cases}$$
hence $f(f(n))<n$ for all $n>2.$